# syslog shows a bunch of FF messages

Tags: lineageos, kernel

When I run `dmesg` I see a bunch of these errors,

```
FF SUSPEND INT                  0 ?\x09
FF WAKEUP                       0 ?\x09
FF GAD SUS                      0 ?\x09
```

What do these mean? Is this normal?

Comment: Which process throws these errors?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I haven't the slighest idea, that's why I'm asking. =/

Comment: Does that appear in logcat (other than kernel buffer)?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I found the source of the error and answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OnePlus 7 Pro](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/guacamole) port is named "guacamole". You can find the source code at [`LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_guacamole`](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_guacamole). You may want to search for the error here, but if you can't find it check inside the [`setup-makefile.sh`](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_guacamole/blob/lineage-18.1/setup-makefiles.sh#L22), you'll find the line,

```
export DEVICE_COMMON=sm8150-common
```

That means the kernel's source code is located [LineageOS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8150](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8150/). You can also find this link on the in the [documentation page for the port under "kernel link"](https://lineageosroms.com/guacamole/).

If you do a search in the `LineageOS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8150` repository for "GAD SUS" in that repository you'll find the source of this error which is [drivers/usb/dwc3/gadget.c:3654](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8150/blob/e6d67171da58596b763384221e6b4ed0d319f368/drivers/usb/dwc3/gadget.c#L3654). So the problem is in USB Dual Role Device, which is an [ASIC driver described as](https://www.synopsys.com/dw/ipdir.php?ds=dwc_usb_3_0_drd),

> The Synopsys DesignWare® USB 3.0 Dual-Role Device (DRD) Controller is a set of synthesizable soft IP that ASIC/FPGA designers can use to implement a complete **USB 3.0 DRD for 5 Gbps speeds. The USB 3.0 DRD Controller is compliant with the specifications for SuperSpeed, High-Speed, Full-Speed, and Low-Speed USB speeds.** Optimizing development time and minimizing engineering risk, the DesignWare USB 3.0 DRD Controller helps designers bring their host and peripheral designs to market faster for wired and wireless applications such as **smart phones**, tablets, TVs, set-top boxes, cameras, modems, game consoles, PCs, and telecommunications equipment. In addition, the IP is silicon proven in design process nodes from 180-nm to 7-nm.